# Can we set the selection of browser default ?

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

i am running my suite using selenium grid on different ports parallely. i am passing the port and browser to the defaultselenium method statically. Things are running good but i want to run my tests on different instances of grid on different browser.That is not happening with this setup though it is picking port independently that is good but it runs only on single type of browser that is specified in selenium method.Is there any way that my tests picks the browser value as specified on grid instance. Or any way with which we can set default browser value in selenium method ?

Comment: Did you try -forcedBrowserMode option in selenium?

Answer (score 0):

The grid simply makes the browsers available and gives you a single point to connect to (the hub) from your client.  It is up to you to make your code request the browser you want and run your tests in parallel.